# Docker, GitLab and deploying an image to AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, gitlab, yaml

I am trying to learn how to create a `.gitlab-ci.yml` and am really struggling to find the resources to help me. I am using dind to create a docker image to push to the docker hub, then trying to log into my AWS EC2 instance, which also has docker installed, to pull the image and start it running.

I have successfully managed to build my image using GitLab and pushed it to the docker hub, but now I have the problem of trying to log into the EC2 instance to pull the image.

My first naive attempt looks like this:

```yaml
#.gitlab-ci.yml
image: docker:18.09.7

variables:
  DOCKER_REPO: myrepo
  IMAGE_BASE_NAME: my-image-name
  IMAGE: $DOCKER_REPO/$IMAGE_BASE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  CONTAINER_NAME: my-container-name

services:
  - docker:18.09.7-dind

before_script:
  - docker login -u "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD"

after_script:
  - docker logout

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build . -t $IMAGE -f $PWD/staging.Dockerfile
    - docker push $IMAGE

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    RELEASE_IMAGE: $DOCKER_REPO/$IMAGE_BASE_NAME:latest
  script:
    - docker pull $IMAGE
    - docker tag $IMAGE $IMAGE
    - docker push $IMAGE
    - docker tag $IMAGE $RELEASE_IMAGE
    - docker push $RELEASE_IMAGE
# So far so good - this is where it starts to go pear-shaped
    - apt-get install sudo -y
    - sudo apt install openssh-server -y
    - ssh -i $AWS_KEY $AWS_URL "docker pull $RELEASE_IMAGE"
    - ssh -i $AWS_KEY $AWS_URL "docker rm --force $CONTAINER_NAME"
    - ssh -i $AWS_KEY $AWS_URL "docker run -p 3001:3001 -p 3002:3002 -w "/var/www/api" --name ${CONTAINER_NAME} ${IMAGE}"
```

It seems that whatever operating system the docker image is built upon does not have `apt-get`, `ssh` and a bunch of other useful commands installed. I receive the following error:

> /bin/sh: eval: line 114: apt-get: not found

Can anyone help me with the commands I need to log into my EC2 instance and pull and run the image in `gitlab-ci.yml` using this docker:dind image? Upon which operating system is the docker image built?

Comment: what is `my-image-name` of your script above ?

Comment: What's the base image used?

Comment: `my-image-name` is the name of the image I'm creating

Comment: The base image is `node:latest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) is based on [Alpine Linux](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/0bab8e3d0ebe6dc4b7a122bb1d0b2e017925c50d/19.03/Dockerfile#L1), which uses the [`apk` package manager](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management).

Try replacing your `apt-get` commands with the following instead:

```yaml
    - apk add openssh-client
```

There is no need to install `sudo`, just to install `openssh-server`, so that step was removed.

Comment: Looks like OP does not use ssh server so I would install `openssh-client` instead.

Comment: A combination of @rage & @makozaki solved the issue. Now I have another error. I get a ` Host key verification failed.` trying to run `ssh -i $AWS_KEY $AWS_URL "docker pull $RELEASE_IMAGE"`. I have checked that the $AWS_KEY file variable and $AWS_URL are correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you connect over ssh to AWS instance locally using the credentials from CI?

Comment: Did you store AWS_KEY  as GitLab file type variable?

Comment: I did. $AWS_KEY is a file and $AWS_URL is a variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210674/discussion-between-makozaki-and-serlingpa).